# Reload the external file on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the below script i am loading a external HTML file to a div with id.

And its working fine.

But I need to reload the external file , every time i click on the button.

The external file is loaded to div inside a model popup. when click on the button the model popup comes up and show the slider (external file) and after closing the model popup, when we press the button second time the popup comes up but not the slider. so i just planed to refresh the external files each time i press the button.

```
<div id="myModel">

<div id="div" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>

</div>

<!-- script for ajax load -->

$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div").load("sliderifame.html");
});

<!-- script for model popup -->

 $('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('#myModel').modal();
    return false;
});

<!-- sliderifame.html content -->

    <div class="mygallery">
    <div class="tn3 album">
        <h4>Fixed Dimensions</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Images with fixed dimensions</div>
        <div class="tn3 thumb">images/35x35/1.jpg</div>
        <ol>
        <li>

            <a href="images/presentation/Slide01.jpg">

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>

            <a href="images/presentation/Slide02.jpg">

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>

            <a href="images/presentation/Slide03.jpg">

            </a>
        </li>

        </ol>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tn3lite.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
$('a.media').media({width:620, height:410});
</script>  

<!--  initialize the TN3 when the DOM is ready -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Thumbnailer.config.shaderOpacity = 1;
        var tn1 = $('.mygallery').tn3({
skinDir:"skins",
imageClick:"fullscreen",
image:{
maxZoom:1.5,
crop:true,
//clickEvent:"dblclick",
transitions:[{
type:"blinds"
},{
type:"grid"
},{
type:"grid",
duration:460,
easing:"easeInQuad",
gridX:1,
gridY:8,
// flat, diagonal, circle, random
sort:"random",
sortReverse:false,
diagonalStart:"bl",
// fade, scale
method:"scale",
partDuration:360,
partEasing:"easeOutSine",
partDirection:"left"
}]
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having though?

Comment: i need to reload (refresh) the sliderifame.html every time i click the button. For making it more clear, the slideriframe.html should refresh each time i click the button

Comment: your code DOES do it! did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

your code already make refresh page on each click .
but your page is html file and you must prevent from caching

my solution is using query string to prevent caching :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    url = "sliderifame.html";
    url += '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime();
    $("#div").load(url);
});
```

as your comments your problem is the load content in modal window 
and as I said you must use iframe modal windows and prevent contents from caching

I have edited your code as below

```
$(function () {
    var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        close: function () {
            iframe.attr("src", "");
        }
    });
    $("#button").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //change url with your sliderifram.html
        var url = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/r6uq14v6/1/show/"; 
        url += '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime();

        var src = url;
        var title = "slider content";
        var width = 600;
        var height = 600;
        iframe.attr({
            width: +width,
            height: +height,
            src: src
        });
        dialog.dialog("option", "title", title).dialog("open");
    });
});
```

note that libraries must use jquery and jquery ui for dialogs

source code of main page : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uoLjm90y/19/)
source code of slider : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r6uq14v6/2/)

Comment: Its not working. Actually i have a slider inside sliderifame.html. and when click the button the slider comes and work in a popup. but when i close the popup and click the button again the slider is not working. but if i refresh the page it work for one time and same again

Comment: @Sam then it is another problem other than load.

Comment: your pop up is modal window ?

Comment: @Farshad yes its a modal popup

Comment: you must use same way to prevent this problem. update call url for your modal window with adding a query string same as my answer. note that you must use iframe load page for modal window and set query string to modal window url

Comment: <div id="#myModel">

    <div id="div" style="width:500px; height:400px;"></div>

</div>


$('#button').click(function (e) {
  $('#myModel').modal();
  return false;
});

Comment: as I said, you must change your call method to load ifram with query string in dialog or modal window to prevent caching . for example  `url = "your-slider-content-for-modal.html";
    url += '?_=' + (new Date()).getTime(); $("#dialog").load(url).dialog({dialogoptions});`

Comment: I have Edited your code . follow jsfiddle link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/uoLjm90y/14/) and your slider page [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r6uq14v6/2/)